# How to define a custom RGB background colour in VIM?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to define a custom RGB colour for the background colour of VIM?

At the moment I use `set background=dark` in my `.vimrc` which assigns `#5D5D5D` for the background colour. However, I would prefer to have `#3F3F3F` for my background colour.

Comment: are you talking about vim or gvim?

Comment: About plain vim in combination with Urxvt terminal.

Comment: read this. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal

Comment: also this program may help you too. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally your terminal will support only 256 colors, and they are numbered. If you want to use a particular color but don't know the number, the script [gui2term.py](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2778) will help you to find the most approximate one. Or you can just pick one from a table like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aXterm_256color_chart.svg).

If you are designing or modifying for your own color scheme for Vim, you can also use gui2term.py to translate those colors to the numbers.

Once you get the color number you'd like to use, you can edit your color scheme file. changing (or adding) the `ctermbg` value for the `Normal` and `NonText` group may be enough. E.g.:

```
highlight Normal guifg=#e0e0e0 guibg=#242424 gui=NONE ctermfg=254 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE
highlight NonText guifg=#99968b guibg=#242424 gui=NONE ctermfg=246 ctermbg=235 cterm=NONE
```

There is a nice HTML [Vim color scheme editor](http://lilydjwg.vim-cn.com/articles/vim-color-modified.html). You can try this to figure out which part uses which group and if you like, edit the colors visually (and run `gui2term.py` against the result file to make it support color terminals).